# Why is my implementation of Atkin sieve is slower than Eratosthenes?

Tags: ruby, algorithm, primes

I'm doing problems from Project Euler in Ruby and implemented Atkin's sieve for finding prime numbers but it runs slower than sieve of Eratosthenes. What is the problem?

```
def atkin_sieve(n)
  primes = [2,3,5]

  sieve = Array.new(n+1, false)

  y_upper = n-4 > 0 ? Math.sqrt(n-4).truncate : 1
  for x in (1..Math.sqrt(n/4).truncate) 
    for y in (1..y_upper)
      k = 4*x**2 + y**2
      sieve[k] = !sieve[k] if k%12 == 1 or k%12 == 5
    end
  end

  y_upper = n-3 > 0 ? Math.sqrt(n-3).truncate : 1
  for x in (1..Math.sqrt(n/3).truncate)
    for y in (1..y_upper)
      k = 3*x**2 + y**2
      sieve[k] = !sieve[k] if k%12 == 7
    end
  end

  for x in (1..Math.sqrt(n).truncate)
    for y in (1..x)
      k = 3*x**2 - y**2
      if k < n and k%12 == 11
    sieve[k] = !sieve[k]
      end
    end
  end

  for j in (5...n)
    if sieve[j]
      prime = true
      for i in (0...primes.length)
        if j % (primes[i]**2) == 0
          prime = false
          break
        end
      end
      primes << j if prime
    end
  end
  primes
end

def erato_sieve(n)
  primes = []
  for i in (2..n)
    if primes.all?{|x| i % x != 0}
      primes << i
    end
  end
  primes
end
```

Comment: Your "erato_sieve" is not even remotely related to the Sieve of Eratosthenes ... it is, rather, an inefficient version of http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trial_division

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As [Wikipedia says](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_number#Sieves), "The modern sieve of Atkin is more complicated, but faster *when properly optimized*" (my emphasis).

The first obvious place to save some time in the first set of loops would be to stop iterating over `y` when `4*x**2 + y**2` is greater than `n`. For example, if `n` is 1,000,000 and `x` is 450, then you should stop iterating when `y` is greater than 435 (instead of continuing to 999 as you do at the moment). So you could rewrite the first loop as:

```
for x in (1..Math.sqrt(n/4).truncate)
    X = 4 * x ** 2
    for y in (1..Math.sqrt(n - X).truncate)
        k = X + y ** 2
        sieve[k] = !sieve[k] if k%12 == 1 or k%12 == 5
    end
end
```

(This also avoids re-computing `4*x**2` each time round the loop, though that is probably a very small improvement, if any.)

Similar remarks apply, of course, to the other loops over `y`.

---

A second place where you could speed things up is in the strategy for looping over `y`. You loop over all values of `y` in the range, and then check to see which ones lead to values of `k` with the correct remainders modulo 12. Instead, you could just loop over the right values of `y` only, and avoid testing the remainders altogether.

If `4*x**2` is 4 modulo 12, then `y**2` must be 1 or 9 modulo 12, and so `y` must be 1, 3, 5, 7, or 11 modulo 12. If `4*x**2` is 8 modulo 12, then `y**2` must be 5 or 9 modulo 12, so `y` must be 3 or 9 modulo 12. And finally, if `4*x**2` is 0 modulo 12, then `y**2` must be 1 or 5 modulo 12, so `y` must be 1, 5, 7, 9, or 11 modulo 12.

---

I also note that your sieve of Eratosthenes is doing useless work by testing divisibility by all primes below `i`. You can halt the iteration once you've test for divisibility by all primes less than or equal to the square root of `i`.

Comment: There are more issues about optimizing implementations of the Sieve of Atkin:  see the [new edited Wikipedia article for new pseudo code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Atkin).  Using the modulo 12 simplification adds about 23% to the work as compared to using modulo 60, and almost half of the calculations are rejected by the modulo tests, which can be corrected by adding a middle loop to test each start number of a modulo sequence, then replicating the sequence through the array.  Finally, SoA is never faster than a maximally wheel factorized SoE for practical ranges.

Answer (score 4):

It would help a lot if you actually implemented the Sieve of Eratosthenes properly in the first place.

The critical feature of that sieve is that you only do one operation per time a prime divides a number.  By contrast you are doing work for every prime less than the number.  The difference is subtle, but the performance implications are huge.

Here is the actual sieve that you failed to implement:

```
def eratosthenes_primes(n)
    primes = []
    could_be_prime = (0..n).map{|i| true}
    could_be_prime[0] = false
    could_be_prime[1] = false
    i = 0
    while i*i <= n
        if could_be_prime[i]
            j = i*i
            while j <= n
                could_be_prime[j] = false
                j += i
            end
        end
        i += 1
    end
    return (2..n).find_all{|i| could_be_prime[i]}
end
```

Compare this with your code for finding all of the primes up to 50,000.  Also note that this can easily be sped up by a factor of 2 by special casing the logic for even numbers.  With that tweak, this algorithm should be fast enough for every Project Euler problem that needs you to compute a lot of primes.

Comment: yes. each composite is *generated* from its prime factors only (below its sqrt), but each candidate is *tested* by *all* the preceding primes (below its sqrt).

Answer (score 1):

@Gareth mentions some redundant calculations regarding 4x^2+y^2. Both here and in other places where you have calculations within a loop, you can make use of calculations you've already performed and reduce this to simple addition.

Rather than `X=4 * x ** 2`, you could rely on the fact that `X` already has the value of `4 * (x-1) ** 2`. Since 4x^2 = 4(x-1)^2 + 4(2x - 1), all you need to do is add `8 * x - 4` to `X`. You can use this same trick for `k`, and the other places where you have repeated calculations (like 3x^2 + y^2).

Comment: Once upon a time this kind of micro-optimization was important, but I think that even in languages like C, it makes little difference these days, as most processors can start (and in some cases, complete) a new multiplication every cycle. And in interpreted languages like Ruby, the interpretation overhead dwarfs any saving you might make by this kind of change.

Comment: In particular, you're proposing here to replace a multiplication by two additions. It's entirely possible that this will make things slower!